# Explain why a variable created in a else if logic statement does not exist in the outer context

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone explain why given the below code I can access myInt but not myInt2?

```
if(int.TryParse("10", out int myInt))
{
    //Do Something
}
else if(int.TryParse("100", out int myInt2))
{
    // Do Something else
}

System.Console.WriteLine(myInt);
System.Console.WriteLine(myInt2); //<-- Compile Error 'myInt2 doesnt exist in the current context
```

Comment: different scope, `If` is called every time `else if` not

Answer (score 6):

It's because:

```
if (condition)
{
    // ...
}
else if (otherCondition)
{
    // ...
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (condition)
{
    // ...
}
else 
{
    if (otherCondition)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now you can see why the scope is different. The second `if` is nested in the `else` block.

Note that a variable introduced inside the condition for an `if` is introduced into the scope of the `else` part of that `if`, as well as the scope following the `if` - but a nested `if` will introduce a variable into the scope for the nested `if` so it won't be visible to the outer `if`'s scope.

(I had a look in the C# standard to provide a reference for this, but I haven't found a good reference yet. I will update this post if I do.)

Incidentally, this scales for multiple if/elses like so:

```
if (init(out int a))
{
    // Can access 'a'here. Cannot access 'b' or 'c'.
}
else if (init(out int b))
{
    // Can access 'a' and 'b' here. Cannot access 'c'.
}
else if (init(out int c))
{
    // Can access 'a', 'b' and 'c' here.
}

// Cannot access 'b' or 'c' here.
```

Is logically the same as:

```
if (init(out int a))
{
    // Can access 'a' here. Cannot access 'b' or 'c'.
}
else
{
    if (init(out int b))
    {
        // Can access 'a' and 'b' here. Cannot access 'c'.
    }
    else
    {
        if (init(out int c))
        {
            // Can access 'a', 'b' and 'c' here.
        }
    }

    // Cannot access 'c' here.
}

// Cannot access 'b' or 'c' here.
```

Answer (score 2):

The `out int name` construct is a different way to simplify code writing. Remember that the code you posted in C# 6 equivalent is:

```
int myInt
if(int.TryParse("10", out myInt))
{
    //Do Something
}
else 
{
    int myInt2
    if(int.TryParse("100", out myInt2))
    {
        // Do Something else
    }
}

System.Console.WriteLine(myInt);
System.Console.WriteLine(myInt2); //<-- Compile Error 'myInt2 doesn't exists
```